# PHP $_POST not carrying over field elements

Tags: php, forms, post, contacts

I'm working on a contact form for a client, but for some reason, it's not carrying over the variables right. Take a look at a bit of the code and see if you can find anything..I'm running out of ideas.

contact.php

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="thankyou.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="1" />
  <table style="width: 500px;">
  <tr>
    <td><p><em><strong>Your email: *</strong></em></p></td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" size="30" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p><em><strong>Subject:</strong></em></p></td>
    <td><input name="subject" type="text" size="30" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p><em><strong>Message: *</strong></em></p></td>
    <td><textarea name="message" type="text" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div style="height:5px"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>To help protect us against spam, please type <em>storage</em> below: *</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="spam_test" maxlength="7" type="text" size="5" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div style="height:5px"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Send" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

thankyou.php

```
<?php
  $user_message = "";
  if(isset($_POST['flag'])) {
    $flag = "true";
    if (strlen($_POST['message']) > 20000) {
      $user_message = "Message too long, please shorten.";
      $flag = "false";
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['message']) < 1) {
      $user_message = "Message cannot be blank.";
      $flag = "false";
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['subject']) > 5000) {
      $user_message = "Subject too long, please shorten.";
      $flag = "false";
    }
    if(!check_email($_POST['email'])) {
      $user_message = "Invalid email address, please re-enter.";
      $flag = "false";
    }
    if($_POST['spam_test'] != "storage") {
      $user_message = "Please fill out the spam prevention field correctly.";
      $flag = "false";
    }
    if($flag == "true") {
      $user_message = "Your message has been sent. We will be in touch shortly.";

      $headers = "From: ContactForm@example.com\r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Return-Path: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";

      $msg = "This is an automatically generated email from the Contact Form on mrstore.co.uk - below is a message from a user:\n\n";
      $msg .= "User's email:  " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
      $msg .= "Message: " . $_POST['message'] . "\n";

      $subject = "Contact Us Message From Website: " . $_POST['subject'];

      if(!mail('user@example.org', $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
      $user_message = "Error Sending Email, please try again later.";
      }
    }
  }
?>
<h2><?php echo $user_message; ?></h2>
```

**EDIT**
The following is the result of print_r($_POST)... Field elements are being carried over to thankyou.php, but are not being processed correctly (ie. spam key is wrong in the example) and the mail is not being sent.

```
Array ( [flag] => true [email] => user@example.org [subject] => This is the subject [message] => hello moto [spam_test] => blah )
```

**EDIT 2**
I feel like I'm getting closer to figuring it out, but now it's throwing a 500 server error. I also created the variable $email in thankyou.php and pointed it to $_POST['email']) Here's the function, check_email...

```
function check_email($email) {
        // First, we check that there's one @ symbol, and that the lengths are right
        if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
            // Email invalid because wrong number of characters in one section, or wrong number of @ symbols.
            return false;
        }
        // Split it into sections to make life easier
        $email_array = explode("@", $email);
        $local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
            if (!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$", $local_array[$i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (!ereg("^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$", $email_array[1])) { // Check if domain is IP. If not, it should be valid domain name
            $domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
            if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) {
                return false; // Not enough parts to domain
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
                if (!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|([A-Za-z0-9]+))$", $domain_array[$i])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**FINAL EDIT...I HOPE!!**
I've narrowed it down to this if statement...

```
if($flag == "true") {
                            $headers = "From: ContactForm@mrstore.co.uk\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Return-Path: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";

                            $msg = "This is an automatically generated email from the Contact Form on mrstore.co.uk - below is a message from a user:\n\n";
                            $msg .= "User's email:  " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
                            $msg .= "Message: " . $_POST['message'] . "\n";

                            $subject = "Contact Us Message From Website: " . $_POST['subject'];
                            mail("dgengler@ccseo.com", $subject, $msg, $headers);
                            $user_message = "Your message has been sent. We will be in touch shortly.";                }
```

Comment: How is it "Not carrying the variables right"? What are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: When I echo $_POST, all that comes up is an empty array. Somehow the variables from the form aren't getting carried over. Not sure why. The method is post...has an action of thankyou.php...all tags are closed.. Would this have anything to do with the fact that it's on a dev subdomain?

Comment: Truth, when the form is submitted to thankyou.php, $_POST is an empty array. No form elements are carried over for processing.

Comment: Try to print_r($_POST); and check if the array contains the form contents.

Comment: But the page is called correctly? (as in if you `echo "Foo";` it works?)

Comment: are you getting a 302 error in your network tab?

Comment: var_dump does provide the form element data. Interesting..

array(5) { ["flag"]=> string(1) "1" ["email"]=> string(18) "asdfasdf@email.com" ["subject"]=> string(0) "" ["message"]=> string(8) "asdfasdf" ["spam_test"]=> string(4) "asdf" }

Currently, there are no rewrite rules in the dev subdomains directory. Could the root .htaccess have an effect on the subdomain?

Comment: Well, you've probably tried `echo $_POST` which would result in `Array` (echo can't print arrays). Which returns me to the original question, what's the problem? Is the mail not sent correctly? Variables not being filled? What?

Comment: @MBY: Will you add this output to the question itself?

Comment: Truth, thanks for clarifying that. I'm relatively new to PHP and wasn't aware that echo only applied to certain things (ie. not arrays).

The current problem is that when the form is submitted...although it is carrying over the elements according to var_dump and print_r...there is no message processing (making sure the message can't be blank, that the spam key is correct, etc). I changed the flag on the contact.php page to true..still nothing though.

Comment: Also, no 302 errors as far as I can tell. The page is being called correctly.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting closer, but now the server is throwing me a 500 error. Not sure if I should continue to feel optimistic at this point or throw my monitors across the room. :p

Comment: I'd answer my own question at the bottom..but apparently new users can't do that for a few hours...anyways...

Figured it out!

First, the email address wasn't properly being processed in the check_email function.
Second, was making sure the flag stayed true throughout. Although it was created with a value of true in the form, it still needed to be created in the thankyou.php file.

Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any problem to send POST data.

Make sure your 'check_email' function is exists. and your email sending function working properly.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to recreate this using your code, the only issue I had was with this line:

```
if(!check_email($_POST['email'])) {
```

Maybe try:

```
if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
```

And see if it works.